# Entity Framework Core Default Sort for Property in configuration entity

Tags: c#, sorting, entity-framework-core

I have some entities which they have `Priority` property. I want to configure default sort for the entities in configuration. One of the entities is like following:

```
public class Country
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Priority {get; set;}
}
```

I also have Config class for the entity. I use Fluent API for configration

```
public class CountryConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
{
   public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Country> builder)
   {
      builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
      builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("NAME");
      builder.Property(x => x.Priority).HasColumnName("PRIORITY");

      builder.Property(x => x.Priority).HasDefaultSortAsc(); // there is no `HasDefaultSortAsc` 
   }
}
```

There is no `HasDefaultSortAsc`method. I want to configure default sort like it or like similar. I can use `OrderBy` when it is call but I want to solve it as global.

I researched a lot but I did not found.
Is there solution like it? How can I do it? Do you have another good idea?

Comment: I think it isn't possible... How manage the case where two entities with default sort are joined?

Comment: As I know it is not possible without Expression Tree transformation. You have to intercept Expression Tree before it will be processed by EF Core and inject OrderBy by itself. Sample of interception: https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/pull/142/files#diff-bc00d2cae4f7b1d89fdf8d0fbdc9ae9b1ea00b906bd2e839c207ec3f8f1f10d5R28

Comment: see to https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-specifying-default-sort-order-in-ef-using-query-interceptors/

Comment: some comments from ef core team https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20460

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem - having a problem X  (perhaps creating a table queue ? Handling optional overriding configs, the way .NET Core does?) and assuming Y is the solution (some "default" sort order for the entire table). There's *no* sort order in SQL without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. Even a clustered key doesn't guarantee the order of results

Comment: To do what you want you'd have to add an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, in SQL, the language. To do so with EF Core, you can use a [command interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors).  I'm not sure if that justifies the complexity though. A `ReadPrioritized` extension method that appends an `OrderBy` clause to an existing query would be more flexible

Comment: @MansurKurtov Did you do it before like it? I tried it but it was not working